# concat - ошибка Value Buffer или чем заменить concat

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть модель Категорий товаров.

```
public class Categories
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Parent_id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Products> Produkt { get; set; }        
    }
```

Где Parent_id это Id выше стоящей категории.
В категории максимум два вложения. 
Основная -> Зависимая 1 -> Зависимая 2

Товар может находится как в Зависимой 1 так и в Зависимой 2.
Как отобрать Все товары исходя из основной?

Пробовал вот так (Parent_id == 3 - это отбор по Id основной категории) :

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {


            var Cetegories1 = from c in _context.Categories.Where(c => c.Parent_id == 3)
                              from p in _context.Categories
                              where c.Id == p.Parent_id
                              select p;
            var Cetegories2 = from c in _context.Categories.Where(c => c.Parent_id == 3)
                              select c;

            var products1 = from p in _context.Products
                            from c in Cetegories1
                            where p.CategoriesId == c.CategoriesId
                            select p;
            var products2 = from p in _context.Products
                            from c in Cetegories2
                            where p.CategoriesId == c.CategoriesId
                            select p;
            var products = products1.Concat(products2);
            return View(products);
        }
```

В этом случае не получается присоединить никакие дочерние элементы.

Если идти от Категорий

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {


            var Cetegories1 = from c in _context.Categories.Where(c => c.Parent_id == 3)
                              from p in _context.Categories
                              where c.Id == p.Parent_id
                              select p;
            var Cetegories2 = from c in _context.Categories.Where(c => c.Parent_id == 3)
                              select c;
            var Cetegories = Cetegories1.Concat(Cetegories2);
            var products = from p in _context.Products
                            from c in Cetegories
                            where p.CategoriesId == c.CategoriesId
                            select p;

            return View(products);
        }
```

То появляется ошибка Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Value Buffer